# How to subtract 60 minutes from current time in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm currently creating a shell script that will run a python code once an hour that collects, processes, and displays data from a radar for the previous hour.

The python code I am using requires a UTC begin time and end time in format "YYYYMMDDHHmm". So far, I have found using the unix command date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M" will retrieve my current time in the correct format, but I have not been able to find a way to subtract 60 minutes from this first time and have it output the "start" time/

code I have tried:

```
date +"%Y%m%d%H%M-60"  >> out: 201908201833-60

now= date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M"  >> out:201908201834

echo "$now - 60"  >> out: - 60
```

I'm just starting to self teach/learn shell coding and I am more comfortable with python coding which is why my attempts are set up more like how you would write with python. I'm sure there is a way to store the variable and have it subtract 60 from the end time, but I have not been able to find a good online source for this (both on here and via Google).

Comment: Which OS and date version do you use?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `-d` option in `date`:

```
date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M" -d '-60 minutes'
```

or else subtract 1 hour instead of 60 minutes:

```
date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M" -d '-1 hour'
```

To be able to capture this value in a variable, use *command substitution*:

```
now=$(date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M" -d '-1 hour')
```

---

On OSX (BSD) use this date command as `-d` is not supported:

```
now=$(date -u -v-1H +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Comment: and capture the value you need as a variable using a shell feature called command-substitution, i.e. `now=$(date ... )`. Good luck to all.

Comment: for each of these three options, I have an error return of illegal time format. I've tried removing and adding spaces along with removing the $ or () from the command substitution, am I not meant to input part of these options? Sorry, I am still very new to the documentation format of unix/shell coding

Comment: Can also use `$: date -d '60 minutes ago'` on some systems.

Comment: The `-u` option to `date` command is crucial in this solution. Man page says: `-u is used to set UTC time`. Otherwise, the value saved would be a number +/- your timezone

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt has some simple shell script errors.

> ```
> now= date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M"  >> out:201908201834
> ```

This assigns an empty string to the variable `now` and then runs the `date` command as previously. If the plan is to capture the output to the variable `now`, the syntax for that is

```
now=$(date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Next up, you try to

> ```
> echo "$now - 60"
> ```

which of course will output the literal string

```
201908201834 - 60
```

rather than perform arithmetic evaluation.  You can say

```
echo "$((now - 60))"
```

to subtract 60 from the value and `echo` that -- but of course, date arithmetic isn't that simple; subtracting 60 from 201908210012 will not produce 201908202312 like you would hope.

If you have GNU `date` (that's a big *if* if you really want to target any Unix) you could simply have done

```
date -u -d "60 minutes ago" +%F%H%M
```

but if you are doing this from Python anyway, performing the date extraction and manipulation in Python too will be a lot more efficient as well as more portable.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.strptime(when,'%Y%m%d%H%M')
print(dt - timedelta(minutes=60))
```

The shell command substitution `$(command)` and arithmetic evaluation `$((expression))` syntaxes look vaguely similar, but are really unrelated. Both of them have been introduced after the fundamental shell syntax was already stable, so they had to find a way to introduce new syntax which didn't already have a well-established meaning in the original Bourne shell.